# SQL: Most Frequent Value with Groupby

Tags: sql, group-by

From this table:

```
SELECT b.id, a.status, a.delivered_at, b.category
FROM `bigquery-public-data.thelook_ecommerce.order_items` a
JOIN `bigquery-public-data.thelook_ecommerce.products` b
ON (a.product_id = b.id)
WHERE status = 'Complete' AND delivered_at BETWEEN "2022-01-01" AND "2022-10-01"
ORDER BY a.delivered_at
LIMIT 5
```

Output:

```
Row id    status    delivered_at            category    
1   4967  Complete  2022-01-01 00:26:00 UTC Jeans
2   8160  Complete  2022-01-01 00:26:00 UTC Suits
3   9018  Complete  2022-01-01 01:18:00 UTC Socks & Hosiery
4   23716 Complete  2022-01-01 02:59:00 UTC Outerwear & Coats
5   49    Complete  2022-01-01 03:21:00 UTC Tops & Tees
```

I wanted a table like this:

```
SELECT extract(month from a.delivered_at) as month, MAX(b.category) as favourite
FROM `bigquery-public-data.thelook_ecommerce.order_items` a
JOIN `bigquery-public-data.thelook_ecommerce.products` b
ON (a.product_id = b.id)
WHERE status = 'Complete' AND delivered_at BETWEEN "2022-01-01" AND "2022-10-01"
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month ASC
```

But i want the favourite column to show the most frequent value for each month, how do i do this?

```
Row month favourite 
 1    1   Underwear
 2    2   Underwear
 3    3   Underwear
 4    4   Underwear
 5    5   Underwear
```

Because i only found how to get the most frequent value without the groupby like this:

```
SELECT b.category
FROM `bigquery-public-data.thelook_ecommerce.order_items` a
JOIN `bigquery-public-data.thelook_ecommerce.products` b
ON (a.product_id = b.id)
WHERE status = 'Complete' AND delivered_at BETWEEN "2022-01-01" AND "2022-02-01"
GROUP BY b.category
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Which give me this:

```
Row category    
1   Jeans
```

If i repeat this code 5 times, by changing the:

```
WHERE status = 'Complete' AND delivered_at BETWEEN "2022-01-01" AND "2022-02-01"
```

For each month, i got:
Jeans for january and february, intimates for march, april and may, so the table i wanted is like this:

```
Row month favourite 
 1    1   Jeans
 2    2   Jeans
 3    3   Intimates
 4    4   Intimates
 5    5   Intimates
```

Comment: can you share your sample data set / tables ? and the expected outcome

Comment: like that one that i just add?

Comment: just share what you have and what you want as the output

Comment: create two tables: current and expected

Comment: how bout now? idk how i can explain any further than that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer by watching this very helpful [video](https://discordapp.com/channels/@me/394853179378106369/1033241853119696916)

So i put this code:

```
SELECT month, category FROM
(SELECT month, category, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY month ORDER BY freq DESC) r FROM
(SELECT extract(month from delivered_at) as month, category, COUNT(DISTINCT order_id) AS freq
FROM `bigquery-public-data.thelook_ecommerce.order_items` a
JOIN `bigquery-public-data.thelook_ecommerce.products` b
ON (a.product_id = b.id)
WHERE status = 'Complete' AND delivered_at BETWEEN "2022-01-01" AND "2022-10-01"
GROUP BY month, category) order_counts) ranked
WHERE r = 1
ORDER BY month
```

and got what i wanted, which is this:

```
|index|month|category|
|---|---|---|
|0|1|Jeans|
|1|2|Jeans|
|2|3|Intimates|
|3|4|Intimates|
|4|4|Fashion Hoodies & Sweatshirts|
|5|4|Tops & Tees|
|6|5|Intimates|
|7|6|Intimates|
|8|7|Swim|
|9|8|Jeans|
|10|9|Jeans|
```